# open images on mobile by tapping

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, plugins, jquery-plugins

I'm looking for a jquery plugin where i can open images on full screen with the option to pinch and zoom (same as facebook on mobile).

in my site i have meta tag that disable the user from zooming

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

my biggest problem (other then the fact that i can't find this plugin) i don't want it to work on desktop. if someone is visiting my site from desktop then this plugin should not work. only on mobile devices

Comment: Can i ask why you're disabling zoom?

Comment: I use this library: [http://quojs.tapquo.com/](http://quojs.tapquo.com/) 

Comment: @DavidAlsbright this is the designers decision. the site has good responsive, no need to zoom unless there are images.

Comment: @kmsdev i don't really understand what is this library

Comment: It is a library to use mobile gestures like pinch, zoom, swipe, rotate. It is not a jQuery plugin, but it is extremely easy to use. You can use it only with mobile devices easily, since it has a boolean which indicates if it is a touch device.